# Can you add CSS to a Dynamic editable area based on an input label value

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using a CMS system that allows you to edit multiple content areas inside the main space (like all of them). What I am trying to do is for each editable content area I want to show a certain background color. The Main-Content = white and the right rail would be red when editing them.

Since everything is generated on the fly once the edit button is clicked, and everything between the two are are the same besides a input value, I am trying to say if the input value = main content show white if the value is right rail show red on **the editor's body tag** `#tinymce.mceContentBody`. **I can only use CSS and I can not add to the HTML (so no adding IDs and classes)**.

Below is a cut out of some of the code generated. If you scroll through it, you will see the line `<input id="label" type="hidden" value="Main-Content" name="label"></input>`. That is the only thing that is different among the two editable areas. One is Main-Content and the other is Right-Right(not shown below). Can this be done? Can I drill down - The only thing I can think of is using that label value, but I am not sure how to code that and if it possible to say it is the parent of the editable area. I tried doing something like this - `input[value="Main-Content"] #tinymce.mceContentBody {background-color:#FFF;}` This failed and I am sure I am coding it incorrectly, but I think there might be something like this that will work.

NOTE this is the code and can not be changed at all -

```
<form id="wysiwyg_form" method="post" action="/servlet/OX/iesave">
<input id="site" type="hidden" value="test-email" name="site"></input>
<input id="path" type="hidden" value="/training/eo/Erick-Test_delete.aspx" name="path"></input>
<input id="newPath" type="hidden" value="/training/eo/Erick-Test_delete.aspx" name="newPath"></input>
<input id="label" type="hidden" value="Main-Content" name="label"></input>
<input id="dest" type="hidden" value="preview" name="dest"></input>
<textarea id="text" rows="1" cols="1" name="text" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
<span id="text_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin" role="application" aria-labelledby="text_voice">
   <span id="text_voice" class="mceVoiceLabel" style="display:none;"></span>
   <table id="text_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation"></tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
                <iframe id="text_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 1000px; height: 703px; display: block;">
                   #document
                      <!DOCTYPE >
                      <html>
                         <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></head>
                         <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody oucampus-wysiwyg" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('text').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr">
                            <p>This is where the content gets displayed - I want this BG to be white and be red when the label above is right rail</p>
```

Comment: "Can this be done?" Can what be done? TinyMCE has a great API to provide CSS inside the editor frame and manipulate the editor contents. Please describe what you are going to do, not how your current solution may look like. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:index

Comment: TinyMCE is inside of WebEpress - I do not have the ability to change anything.  What I am doing is displaying an email template to the end user - when they click to edit I am displaying a bg image of the email and positioning the editor in the general location of where they would be editing - hence giving the end user a feel of what the email will truly look like when they are done.  I can achieve this by using multiple css files.  I want to combine them all into one and say if the end user is trying to edit the main-content show them certain parameters - if it is the right-rail show them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is to use the 'wysiwyg-class' attribute in the either the editor tag inside of your editable regions. That class will be added to the  node of the TinyMCE editor and then one css can modify the margins, width, height position of the body based on the class

```
body.main_content { } 
body.left_column { } 
<!-- com.omniupdate.div ....
<!-- com.omniupdate.editor ... wysiwyg-class="left_column" ...
```